# Can you concatenate multiple arrays from the output of a function without using temporal variables in Python?

Tags: python, function, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

**Problem:**

- The function `f` returns the numpy ndarrays `np_array_1, np_array_2`. Both arrays have the same length, but this length may be different for each call.
- I want to call `f` several times and keep only the two arrays concatenated from the different calls.

**Question:** Is there a way to do it without using temporal variables?
Using temporal variables:

```py
def f(i):
   ...
   return np_array_1, np_array_2

np_array_1, np_array_2 = f(0)
for i in range(1, 5):
   np_array_1_t, np_array_2_t = f(i)
   np_array_1 = np.concatenate(np_array_1, np_array_1_t)
   np_array_2 = np.concatenate(np_array_2, np_array_2_t)
del np_array_1_t, np_array_2_t
```

Comment: concatenate works with a list of many arrays, not just 2.

Comment: @hpaulj What do you mean with this? Why would I use more than two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may make the list operations of the other answer more understandable

```
alist1 = []; alist2 = []
np_array_1, np_array_2 = f(0)
for i in range(0, 5):
   a1, a2 = f(i)
   alist1.append(a1); alist2.append(a2)
np_array_1 = np.concatenate(alist1)
np_array_2 = np.concatenate(alist2)
```

`concatenate` and `array` (and variations) all take a list of arrays as input.  It's better to collect the arrays in one list, and do just on `concatenate`.  List append is more efficient and suitable for iterative application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly the following works:

```
a1s, a2s = zip(*(f(i) for i in range(5)))
a1 = np.concatenate(a1s)
a2 = np.concatenate(a2s)
```

Or even simpler if all arrays have the same size:

```
a1, a2 = np.array([f(i) for i in range(5)]).squeeze().T
```

Comment: In general the arrays in my problem do not have the same size. Your first approach still uses temporal variables, but it is more concise than the method I thought. However, I do not completely understand it. So `(f(i) for i in range(5))` is like a tuple of 5 tuples of 2 arrays? I am a bit lost with the asterisk and the zip...